# Django static/template loaders

Tags: django

I'm using Django 1.8.  Per the docs it says that given the default settings in the development environment you should be able to use the following directories for templates/static files:

```
mysite/main/templates/main/template.html

mysite/main/static/main/style.css
```

With the templates I was required to add `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'main/templates')` to my template dirs.  With the static files I can't get it to find them either way.

The docs seem to show that in development the template/static loaders should automatically find these directories and subsequently the static files and template files, rather than having to define the directories in the settings.  For some reason they are not.  I'm sure that I'm missing something small, but cant quite put my finger on it.

Thanks for any help.

---

Edit:

Within my view, I am calling the template with the render shortcut:

```
from django.shortcuts import render

def index(request):
    data = {}
    return render(request, 'main/index.html', data)
```

Within my template file I am trying to call my static files like so:

```
 {% load staticfiles %}

 <html>
 <head>
      <title>Purple Cross</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static main/css/style.css %}">
 </head>
 <body>
      {% block content %}
      {% endblock %}
 </body>
 </html>
```

---

Edit 2:

main.urls.py:

```
from django.conf.urls import url
from . import views
from django.conf import settings
from django.conf.urls.static import static


urlpatterns = [
    url(r'^$', views.index, name='index'),
] + static(settings.STATIC_URL, document_root=settings.STATIC_ROOT)
```

As far as the settings file goes, here is the only thing relevant to static files (+the installed apps):

```
INSTALLED_APPS = (
     'django.contrib.admin',
     'django.contrib.auth',
     'django.contrib.contenttypes',
     'django.contrib.sessions',
     'django.contrib.messages',
     'django.contrib.staticfiles',
     'main', 
 )   


STATIC_URL = '/static/'
```

Comment: Sorry, I was trying to generalize with mysite/myapp, but the app is actually called 'main'

Comment: Please show your template and static files settings. When you remove `os.path.join(BASE_DIR, 'main/templates')` from template dirs, what directories does the debug page say that it tried? Have you made sure that `main` is in your `INSTALLED_APPS`? Is your project `mysite` actually called `main`?

Comment: Well i did forget to add 'main' to my installed apps.  That fixed the template dirs problem, I no longer have to add the dir to the template dirs.  However the problem with static files still occurs. I'll add a couple possibilities to my edit

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have a misspelling in your template. You need to add quotes around the file directory `href="{% static 'main/css/style.css' %}`

```
{% load staticfiles %}

 <html>
 <head>
      <title>Purple Cross</title>
      <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="{% static 'main/css/style.css' %}">
 </head>
 <body>
      {% block content %}
      {% endblock %}
 </body>
 </html>
```